# How to update DNS records so I can visit a new site?

Tags: networking, dns, 22.04

I hosted a [site](https://omnifood.hasan.one/) on Netlify and used Cname records to point it to my domain name. I can access the site from my Android phone using any browser but not from my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop! When I try to do so I get:

> This site can’t be reached Check if there is a typo in omnifood.hasan.one.
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
> [image]

**What I have done:**

- Flush the DNS records by running `resolvectl flush-caches`.
- Query my site using `resolvectl query omnifood.hasan.one` which returns:

```bash
omnifood.hasan.one: 3.64.200.242               -- link: wlp4s0
                    164.90.180.144             -- link: wlp4s0
                    2a05:d014:275:cb02:66df:50b:6e56:a6bf -- link: wlp4s0
                    2a03:b0c0:3:d0::143f:d001  -- link: wlp4s0
                    (https\058\047\047chic-rugelach-8bf155.netlify.app)
```

The above result shows that the tool can find the correct link for that domain!

Here are my DNS servers:

```
nmcli device show wlp4s0 | grep IP4.DNS

IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.4.4
```

**My Question**:

How can I update my DNS records?

Comment: You have a CNAME for omnifood.hasan.one pointing to https://chic-rugelach-8bf155.netlify.app. (see `dig omnifood.hasan.one`)  I don't think that is right -- you need to review your netlify setup: https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/configure-external-dns/#configure-a-subdomain

Comment: Just noticed my comment was a little mangled. omnifood.hasan.com is pointing to something starting with `https`. This is not correct.

Comment: @WayneVosberg after reading some threads on the subject, I don't think I can turn off https in netlfy. it seems on by default for everyone.

Comment: A CNAME record may NOT point to a URL, only an object that has a corresponding A record. In your instance you should have "omnifood.hasan.one CNAME chic-rugelach-8b155.netify.app".

Comment: @WayneVosberg your last comment solved my problem. thank you. It would be nice if you write it as an answer so that I could mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CNAME record must point only to an object that has a corresponding A record. Pointing to a URL (starting with http[s]:) is not valid. In your instance you should have

```
omnifood.hasan.one. CNAME chic-rugelach-8bf155.netlify.app.
```